# Can I host a competition in multiple locations?

Tags: discussion, king-of-the-hill

I'm interested in running a KOTH in the near future. I would like the competition to be open to as many people as possible, however I know some people that are uninterested in posting answers to Stack Exchange. But I'd also be happy to run it here as well. So I'm wondering if I can host this challenge in multiple locations at the same time. All the entrants (including ones that are not posted to SE) will be competing against each other. Would this be permitted, or must challenges on this site be entirely self-contained?

One concern would be to let every submission be easily visible without needing to go somewhere else to see it. So I'm planning on having every submission be visible on Github and linking that in the challenge so that anyone who wants to answer can see all the submissions so far. Would that be sufficient?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes

But I suggest the following limitations:

- There must be a (possibly external) list of all participants on all submission platforms
- It must be possible to submit a bot on this site only, requiring submission on some external site wouldn't be allowed. Maybe a exception for requiring a PR on github would be ok.

  - This is intended to prevent people from simply promoting a contest here that's primarily hosted somewhere else and answers here have no real effect
- You disclose publicly where else the KOTH is hosted